# How to download any generated by JS file from firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to my extension can generate and save text file inside downloads folder. Just give me example of code how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downloads API is what you are probably looking for:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads

The downloads.download() function lets you download a file from a URL to your Downloads folder. Here is the example based on the [Downloads.download() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download).

```js
function onStartedDownload(id) {
  console.log('Started downloading: ' + id);
}

function onFailed(error) {
  console.log('Download failed: ' + error);
}

var downloadUrl = "https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/home/2018/cards/irl-season-3.821df676279d.png";

var downloading = browser.downloads.download({
  url : downloadUrl,
  filename : 'mozilla-home.png',
  conflictAction : 'uniquify'
});

downloading.then(onStartedDownload, onFailed);
```

If you need to download data created in Javascript, then you'll first have to create a URL for that data using [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)